# Induced emf with no relative motion

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity, electromagnetic-induction

When we change the magnetic flux encompassed by a loop, an induced current is produced. We know that the induced current is often explained with either the motion of loop  with respect to the magnetic field or vice versa.

Let's say I have placed a loop underneath an electromagnet producing constant magnetic field. When I suddenly increase the field produced by electromagnet, we can see that the current is induced eventhough both the field and loop aren't in relative motion to each other. What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2):

It is the change in magnetic flux that induces an emf.  That change can be due to either motion of a loop or a change in the flux through a stationary loop.

Comment: But why does change in magnetic field make the electrons move? I'm unable to find any proper sources that explains this without relative motion of loop or field

Comment: A changing magnetic flux produces an electric field and that field causes the electrons to move. Suggest you consult a good basic physics book, such as one by Halliday and Resnick; then an intermediate level physics textbook on electrodynamics, I like an old one by Kip called Fundamentals of Electricity and Magnetism.

Answer (score 2):

"We know that the induced current is often explained with either the motion of loop with respect to the magnetic field or vice versa."

It is not always possible to explain an induced emf like this. You have given, in your second paragraph, a case where you can't. A transformer embodies just such a phenomenon.

Faraday recognised that there were two sorts of electromagnetic induction; those in which an emf is induced in a moving conductor, and those in which there is a change in flux through a stationary loop. We now attribute the emf in the moving conductor to magnetic Lorentz forces ($\mathbf F =q \mathbf v \times \mathbf B$) acting on the charge carriers, which move as the wire moves. In the other case the emf is due to an electric Lorentz force, $\mathbf F =q \mathbf E$) on the (stationary) charge carriers – if there are charge carriers present in the loop.

One of Maxwell's equations relates this electric field to the local magnetic field, $\mathbf B$:
$$\text{curl}\ \mathbf E =\ –\frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}.$$
This can be integrated over a loop to give $$\oint\mathbf E.d\mathbf l\ =-\int \frac{\partial \mathbf B}{\partial t}.d\mathbf A$$
in which the line integral is around the loop and the area integral is evaluated over any surface bounded by the loop.

Some would say that the changing magnetic field gives rise to the electric field, but I prefer to think of the Maxwell equation as telling us an inherent structural characteristic of a single thing: an electromagnetic field, of which $\mathbf B$ and $\mathbf E$ are two parts.